# Unable to auto print URL data on onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, printing, onclick

onclick I want to open URL and then auto print the url page. this code take me to print page before opening url.

```js
function clickyClick() {
  url = 'http://facebook.com/' + document.getElementById("comment").value
  mywindows = window.open(url, '_blank');
  window.print();

}
```

```html
<form>Enter Input:
  <input type="text" name="comments" id="comment">
</form>
<br>
<button onclick="clickyClick()">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Which window do you want to print? You're printing the current window, you need to use `mywindows.print()` to print the new window.

Comment: @Barmar mywindows.print() doent print show any print dialogue

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Put the print function in a callback, and call the callback on window load

```
function clickyClick() {
            url = 'http://facebook.com/' + document.getElementById("comment").value
           mywindows = window.open(url, '_blank');
           mywindows.onload = function() {
              window.print();
           };
}
```

callback ensures that the url is printed after the window has been loaded.

Comment: Thank you giri, can you please help me to write callback for this ?